# How can it delete the object without writing destroy function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a survey, follows the http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=asciicast

I can create a survey, questions, answers by `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

A survey has many questions,

A questions has many answers,

I wonder know what's the logic to delete a question.

I just need to check the box and update the objects, and it will delete the question object in the model ?

Why ? I thought I need to perform the destroy method in the controller via checking if the checkbox is selected ?

I wonder know, How can the destroy task can be done without writing `OJBECT.destroy` code

### model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    belongs_to :survey
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

### form

```
  = f.check_box :_destroy
  = f.label :_destroy, "Remove Question"
```

### Javascript

```
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
```

### controller.rb

```
  def survey_params
    params.require(:survey).permit(
      :title,
      questions_attributes: [:id, :content, :survey_id, :_destroy,
      answers_attributes:[:id, :content, :question_id, :_destroy]] ,
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your new survey view you only have the forms to create the Questions and Answers, added dynamically at the client side. When you delete, actually you are only deleting the form in client side by triggering a javascript. At this point, the instance of the Model does not exist yet, so you don't need to perform a destroy action in the controller.

Only when you submit your survey that the survey, its questions, and their answers will be creating models and saving then to database.

Comment: Hi, I wonder know, How can the destroy can be done without writing `OJBECT.destroy` code